# Get date from filename in Google Datafusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm new to datafusion, and I would like to get the "date" from the filename and use this date for using it in the table name (Yes, I know it is not the best practice, but it's easier for other people to query a single table..)

How can I do this?

My filenames are like this:
FILENAME_201216.TXT

And I want to get this date, and use in a tablename like this:
TABLENAME_20201216

And (Also) Add a field with this date value to the table.

Is this possible with Google DataFusion? How?

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the general use scenario? Do you plan to import these files to Bigquery? What are the source and sink plugins involved into this?

Comment: The Source is Google Cloud Storage and the Sink is BigQuery. I have files that are uploaded from a local server to Cloud Storage, in format FILENAME_2020XXXX.DAT, and I need to import this files into bigquery. The trouble is that the date is only in the filename and not as a column.

Comment: Data Fusion has no own instruments to handle this task, I can advise you to fetch the data value from the filenames in prior of running the pipeline and settle them as runtime arguments either via Argument Setter or GCS Argument setter, more context you can find in the general [guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/reusable-pipeline#deploy_the_argument_setter_plugin). Does it sound reasonable for you?